# How to configure and combine wildcard domains and subdomains in Apache2's VirtualDocumentRoot?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, subdomain, wildcard

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<Directory "/Volumes/DATA/websites">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Volumes/DATA/websites/default"
    ServerName default.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Volumes/DATA/websites/%1/www"
    ServerAlias *.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

Requests are currently handled as follows:

```
alpha.dev   -> /Volumes/DATA/websites/alpha/www
beta.dev    -> /Volumes/DATA/websites/beta/www
```

Is it possible to have wildcard domains *and* subdomains? E.g.:

```
alpha.dev       -> /Volumes/DATA/websites/alpha/www
img.alpha.dev   -> /Volumes/DATA/websites/alpha/img
cdn.alpha.dev   -> /Volumes/DATA/websites/alpha/cdn

beta.dev        -> /Volumes/DATA/websites/beta/www
docs.beta.dev   -> /Volumes/DATA/websites/beta/docs
blog.beta.dev   -> /Volumes/DATA/websites/beta/blog
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html) multiple parts of a FQDN could be used. In your configuration you are using `%1` which corresponds the subdomain. If the FQDN is `img.alpha.dev` then `%1` would result in `img` and as `%2` corresponds to the domain it results in `alpha` and `%0` to `img.alpha.dev` as `%0` corresponds to FQDN.

Implementing the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, executing `mkdir -p /var/www/mydomain/info && echo helloworld > /var/www/mydomain/info/index.html`, restarting `httpd` and navigating to `http://info.mydomain.com/` results in `helloworld`.

However if a ServerAlias is specified more, e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

executing `mkdir -p /var/www/info && echo test2_param_one > /var/www/info/index.html` and navigating to `info.mydomain.com` results in `test2_param_one`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

executing `mkdir -p /var/www/info.mydomain.com && echo test2_param_all > /var/www/info.mydomain.com/index.html` and navigating to `info.mydomain.com` results in `test2_param_all`.

In conclusion, the following snippet works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.*.dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2/%1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/test
</VirtualHost>
```

`mkdir -p /var/www/alpha/test && echo test5 > /var/www/alpha/test/index.html`, `mkdir -p /var/www/alpha/img && echo test10 > /var/www/alpha/img/index.html`, navigating to `http://alpha.dev/` returns `test5` and navigating to `http://img.alpha.dev/` returns `test10`.

Comment: Wouldn't this trigger a overlap with the first declared vhost winning?

Comment: I looked at the doc.. i'm new to the server stuff... developer by trade by just haven't gotten into server stuff. What is the explanation between %0, %1... etc